# How to Write Unit Tests for Primefaces/JSF Apps

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, junit

Does anyone know of a simple way that I can write Java unit tests for Primefaces or other JSF-based web applications?  I found this blog from Primefaces' creator:

https://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2009/09/08/easy-unit-testing-jsf-backing-beans/

... but it's from 2009, and recommends using Java with [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) and [JUnit](http://junit.org/).  I'm not sure if there have been any new fangled advances in unit test coding since that time which make creating unit tests for Primefaces even easier.

Other sources recommend using Java with [JSFUnit](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-9819?uniqueTitle=false), which looks like it has some issues and is not intuitive for myself to set up.

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: How on earth can a question about how to write units tests be off-topic in Stack Overflow?  Ridiculous.  Is this not a programming discussion website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). 
**Selenium client API:**
As an alternative to writing tests in Selenese, tests can also be written in various programming languages. These tests then communicate with Selenium by calling methods in the Selenium Client API. Selenium currently provides client APIs for Java, C#, Ruby and Python. [Read More...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29)

**Examples :**
[Testing JSF applications
with Arquillian and Selenium](http://www.bleathem.ca/talks/2012-JavaOne/testing-jsf.html) 
[Java testing with Selenium and dynamic ids in html](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/java-testing-with-selenium-and-dynamic-ids-in-html.html)